# 'An instance 0x7c37edd0 of class PlayingTimer was deallocated while key value observers were still registered with it. Current observation

Tags: ios, memory, dealloc

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'An instance 0x7c37edd0 of class PlayingTimer was deallocated while key value observers were still registered with it

Comment: Thank you for the information! And, what's the question?

Comment: i have used audio recorder.its record the audio input.when iam press back button its throw this error.

Comment: I believe you are adding some notification observer to `PlayingTimer` class but not removing it in `dealloc` method. Remove the observer in `dealloc`.

Comment: ya iam removing the observer .but this error till happed to me.                                        [recorder stop];
 AVAudioSession *audioSession = [AVAudioSession sharedInstance];
        [audioSession setActive:NO error:nil];
        
        [self stopGame];
        [timer removeObserver:self forKeyPath:@"timeText"];

Comment: It will be helpful if you include all relevant code snippets in your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You didn't actually ask a question, but it seems you posted the answer.

Read what the exception says. It says exactly what went wrong. You have an object with observers. At some point the dealloc method of the object is called. After dealloc is called it still has observers. If you have observers after dealloc is called, your app will crash. So you must make sure that there are no observers after dealloc is called.

Comment: thanx bro.sry for late wish